# Ubuntu 16.04 wifi hotspot access localhost

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, wifi

I have a website on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, the website is running on a LAMP stack. Machine does not have access to the internet so I am creating a new Hotspot connection on it and connect to it.

Now I want to connect to this Hotspot and browse the website on localhost on the Ubuntu machine from another laptop. I am able to connect to the hotspot but I am not able to view the website at `localhost/website/`. I am getting a refused connection error.

I tried replacing `localhost` with the `ip` I get when writing `ifconfing` in the console on the Ubuntu machine, but still no success.

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience,the Hotspot you create can't connect to your local server,because they are not in the same network channel.For example,your ip is 192.168.1.45,but your another laptop ip maybe is 192.168.0.25, they not in the same gateway.

My suggestion is you can use your phone as Hotspot, then connect both of you laptop on the hotspot.